# MySQL8.0 xdevapi node.js doesn't return keys, only values

Tags: node.js, mysql-8.0

Using MySQL 8.0 on a node.js server (X DevAPI), I'm trying to get data with

```
var res = session.sql('SELECT * FROM users').execute(function (row) {
  console.log(row); // [1,'foo','bar']
});
```

but this returns only an array of values. The column names are missing. Is there a way I can get key-value pairs such as that in classic SQL data sets?

i.e. `id: 1, fName: 'foo', lName: 'bar'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you would have to construct the key-value pair structure "by hand" using the [column metadata](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-Column.html) available through a second [callback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-SqlExecute.html) parameter on `execute()`.

Something like the following would do the trick:

```
var result = []

session.sql('SELECT 1 AS id, "foo" AS fName, "bar" AS lName')
  .execute(row => {
    row.forEach((value, i) => { result[i] = Object.assign({}, result[i], { value }) })
  }, columns => {
    columns.forEach((key, i) => { result[i] = Object.assign({}, result[i], { key: key.getColumnName() }) })
  })

console.log(result.reduce((res, pair) => Object.assign(res, { [pair.key]: pair.value }), {}))
```

I have to admit this is convoluted and making it better is already on the radar.

Disclaimer: I'm the X DevAPI connector lead dev.

Comment: I was affraid of that. Thank you for clearing that up though, I'll move forward with that in mind.

Comment: You did a brilliant job! 
I hope that this connector will have a great future!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [JSON_OBJECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) function in your query.

```
 var res = session.sql("select JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'name', name) from users").execute(function (row) {
      console.log(row); // {"id": 87, "name": "rui"} 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround maybe will help someone.

```
    //This is declared outside of class
    const mapTest = (row) =>{
    return{
            id:row[0],
            price:row[1]
        }
    }
    //This where you get the result.
    .execute()
    .then(myResult =>{
          let myRows = myResult.fetchAll();
          resolve(myRows.map(row=>mapTest(row))); // returns {"id":1,"price":200000},{"id":2,"price":300000}
    })
```